# flutter title automatically go to next line

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

the code below is in wrapped in a row. i need help in getting the text to automatically go to the next line when there's not enough space. ive been trying to wrap in expanded and stuff but it is not working and throwing me the wrong use of parent widget error. tia

[image]

```
Expanded(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children:  [
            Text(
              Helpers.getChannelName(channel, context.currentUser!),
              overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                fontSize: 21,
                
              ),
              maxLines: null,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 2),
          ],
        )),
```

Comment: If you are putting in on appBar, it has limited height `ktoolBarHeight`, If it is ok to change font size, you can wrap text with `FittedBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AppBar` has limited height, you can have some(2/3) lines like

```dart
Text(
  Helpers.getChannelName(channel, context.currentUser!),
  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
    fontSize: 21,
  ),
  maxLines: 3,
  softWrap: true,
),
```

Also, you can try changing text size by wrapping `Text` widget with `FittedBox` or using [`auto_size_text`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)

Comment: Glad to help you out. you can check more about [AppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)